# JS output - console.log vs innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code in with Free JS Editor. But nothing is printed on the build in preview browser. 
I got this exercise from codecademy and while using console.log (on their site) it prints out the first and last names (like it should ,,, i think)
What am i doing wrong that its not printing on my desktop software?
Also you guys suggest a free JS editor for some training purposes?

```
    <body>
    <p id="text"></p>
    <script>
     var bob = {
     firstName: "Bob",
     lastName: "Jones",
     phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
     email: "bob.jones@example.com"
     };

     var mary = {
     firstName: "Mary",
     lastName: "Johnson",
     phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
     email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
     };

     var contacts = [bob, mary];
     function printPerson(person){
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=(person.firstName + " " +person.lastName);
     };

     function list () {    
     var contactsLength = contacts.length;
     for (i=0; i<contactsLength; i++) {
     printPerson(contacts[i]);
     };
     };
     list;





    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: By "desktop software" do you mean "browser"?

Comment: What is "desktop software"? Free JS Editor?

Comment: console.log prints to the developer console while innerHTML maniplulates the DOM

Comment: Please [indent your code](http://jorendorff.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/why-do-we-indent-code.html?m=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` is a function. To call the function (make it run) you need to use brackets, even if it doesn't have any parameters.

Change `list;` to `list();`

*Edit:*

You also overwrite the previous content in the `p` tag every time the function is called. So you're not listing the names, you're writing a name then replacing the name with each loop. I fixed it in the JSFiddle.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hgxc2cL/2)

Comment: Quicker than me :p

Comment: @Andy I found it on code academy, they use the brackets. The OP just forgot: https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/4fcd767bb56ba0000302ad35

Comment: I am using Yaldex Software Free JS Editor. But JSFiddle seems better.

Comment: Many, many JS editors are free. I wouldn't trust one that advertises how free it is like that. JSFiddle and Codepen are good online editors. For more full desktop IDEs check out Visual Studio Community Edition, JetBrains Webstorm, Brackets, or tons of other better ones.